# "Couldn't resolve host" error

Tags: linux, centos

We've recently setup "New Relic" on our web server. This is a great tool to measure full-stack performance.

The problem is we cannot get to run New relic for more than 10-15 minutes during our peak times. For some reason our website stops responding. And we have to stop the new relic daemon to bring the web server up (Apache).

An important log file for New Relic is "newrelic-daemon.log". This log shows the following line just before things come to a halt:

> "2012-02-09 22:01:29 [26035/timer] error: RPM command 'metric_data'
>   failed(6): Couldn't resolve host 'collector-7.newrelic.com'"

So I'm thinking the problem is with our own server. Where should I look to further investigate the problem?

**UPDATE**:
/etc/resolv.conf content:

```
search ourdomain.com
nameserver 94.101.94.4
nameserver 94.101.95.4
```

Comment: That's a DNS error.  Can you update your post with the contents of /etc/resolv.conf?

Comment: How about if I add google "nameserver 8.8.8.8" to resolv.conf? Does this make sense?

Comment: It turns out what stopped new relic was our httpd.conf. ServerLimit 
and MaxClients were both set to: 1024 . We reduced bothm of them to 950 and now all is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, try using "nameserver 8.8.8.8" and "nameserver 8.8.4.4".  There might some other issues, possibly related to load, but that's a reasonable first try.

The IPs that you currently have are for public1.radore.net and public2.radore.net.  Are those your hosting provider?

Comment: Yes those belong to the hosting provider. Still we received the same error. Maybe New Relic is reporting a wrong error. Having tried the google name servers, I'm not entirely sure anymore if the problem is with the nameservers.

Comment: What's the load on the boxes when NewRelic and Apache are non-responsive?  I think it's less likely that DNS resolution is the issue.  It's more likely it's the symptom of some other problem.

Comment: Great question! That's exactly what I pin-pointed a few moments ago. New Relic process is consuming 100% CPU when Apache is unresponsive. Probably that's why Apache is unresponsive (and probably any other processes on the server for that matter.) Killing the New Relic process resolves the issue instantly. Normally New Relic does not consume 100% cpu.

Comment: OK, now you have to figure out why NewRelic is pegged.  That might be a support email to them, actually.  I've found them responsive in the past.

Comment: According to the daemon logs `2012-02-13 15:43:12 [25947/listener] verbosedebug: accept() failed with: 24: Too many open files [repeated 8697 times]` there seems to be an error related to the count of open files.

Comment: Oh.  That's something to do with ulimits, and possibly max file counts, then.  Take a look at `ulimit -a` for the user the app runs under. You'll be looking at the "open files" number.  If it's low, you can try editing /etc/security/limits.conf and adding a line like "* hard nofile 4096" (check your docs). There's also a system-wide number show in /proc/sys/fs/file-max but it's unlikely you'll hit that.